# Convert a homogenous matrix from xyz coordinate system to zyx coordinate system

Tags: python, coordinate-system, 3d, affine-transformation, deep-learning

I want to change my camera pose from xyz coordinate system(where x-forward direction, y left and z up) to zyx coordinate system ( z-forward y- down and x left)

My camera pose is described in an homogenous matrix. Let's take this matrix as an example:

```
Camera = [ 1 0 0 1,
          0 1 0 2,
          0 0 1 3,
          0 0 0 1]
```

i created this function which rotate the matrix but i'm not sure if it's working correctly

```
def rotate_homogeneous_matrix(original_matrix, axis, angle_degrees):
"""
Rotate a 4x4 homogeneous matrix in a specified direction by a given angle.

Parameters:
- original_matrix (numpy.ndarray): The original homogeneous matrix.
- axis (str): The rotation axis ('X', 'Y', or 'Z').
- angle_degrees (float): The rotation angle in degrees.

Returns:
- numpy.ndarray: The rotated homogeneous matrix.
"""
# Ensure the matrix is 4x4
if original_matrix.shape != (4, 4):
    raise ValueError("Input matrix must be a 4x4 homogeneous matrix")

# Convert angle to radians
angle_radians = np.radians(angle_degrees)

# Create a copy of the matrix to avoid modifying the original
rotated_matrix = np.copy(original_matrix)

# Define rotation matrices based on the specified axis
if axis == 'X':
    rotation_matrix = np.array([
        [1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, np.cos(angle_radians), -np.sin(angle_radians), 0],
        [0, np.sin(angle_radians), np.cos(angle_radians), 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]
    ])
elif axis == 'Y':
    rotation_matrix = np.array([
        [np.cos(angle_radians), 0, np.sin(angle_radians), 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [-np.sin(angle_radians), 0, np.cos(angle_radians), 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]
    ])
elif axis == 'Z':
    rotation_matrix = np.array([
        [np.cos(angle_radians), -np.sin(angle_radians), 0, 0],
        [np.sin(angle_radians), np.cos(angle_radians), 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]
    ])
else:
    raise ValueError("Invalid axis. Use 'X', 'Y', or 'Z'.")

# Apply rotation
rotated_matrix = np.matmul(rotated_matrix, rotation_matrix)

return rotated_matrix


pose = rotate_homogeneous_matrix(camera, "Y", 90)
pose = rotate_homogeneous_matrix(pose, "Z", -90)
```

I'm only rotating the axes. Do I need to change the order of the translation vector element? Does this function implementation satisfy the target.